# Printing coeficients of several linear regressions on a single python script

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression, coefficients

I am running this code:

```
import sklearn
IVS=['CRIM', 'RM', 'PTRATIO']
IVS2=['CRIM','PTRATIO']
model1=lm.fit(bos[IVS],bos.PRICE)
model2=lm.fit(bos[IVS2],bos.PRICE)

print(model1.coef_)
print(model2.coef_)
```

When trying to print out the coefficients for both models, I only get the last model coef for both print functions:

```
[-0.27939868 -1.83737204]
[-0.27939868 -1.83737204]
```

Any idea why this is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create separate instances of your classifier before you call fit:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression()
model1 = LinearRegression()
model1.fit(bos[IVS],bos.PRICE)
model2 = LinearRegression()
model2.fit(bos[IVS2],bos.PRICE)
```